# Find similar items from an array filtered by the provided data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-native, sorting

trying to solve the problem here. so I have an array of objects and the object contains some properties and their values. so I want to find the objects that have similar values filtered by the props that I'm providing.

here's the code that I've done but the issue is I need to have all the object's properties have the same values as each other.

```
const data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'ali',
        class: 12,
        thisSec: true
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'vicks',
        class: 11,
        thisSec: false
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'ali',
        class: 12,
        thisSec: true
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'vicks',
        class: 11,
        thisSec: false
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        name: 'nick',
        class: 10,
        thisSec: true
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        name: 'lick',
        class: 12,
        thisSec: false
    },
]

const checkFilter = (id, searchCritera) => {
    if(id && searchCritera.length) {
        const selectedItem = data.find(item => item.id === id)
        
        const dataneeded = []
        searchCritera.forEach((item) => {
            data.forEach(dataItem => {
                if(dataItem.id !== selectedItem.id) {
                    if(dataItem[item] === selectedItem[item]) {
                        const ifElemExists = dataneeded.find(dataNeddedItem => dataNeddedItem.id == dataItem.id)
                        if(!ifElemExists) {
                            dataneeded.push(dataItem)   
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        })
        
        console.log('dataneeded ', dataneeded);
    }
}

checkFilter(1, [
    'name',
    'class'
])
```

**output:**
[image]

I am filtering with name and class props but the output I'm getting is having the name as different values.

any help would be really appreciated. thanks.

Comment: So you want to find objects that have the same `name` _and_ `class` here? But you are adding an item to your result each time it fulfills only _one_ of those conditions already.

Comment: ya, I realized that. not getting any solution in mind. it should be something like if I am searching for name and class together, all the resulting objects should have the same name and class values to each other otherwise empty array should return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Array#filter` method to filter based on `selectedItem` properties supplied. To exclude `selectedItem` use `o.id !== id` as in the demo below:

```js
const data = [ { id: 1, name: 'ali', class: 12, thisSec: true }, { id: 2, name: 'vicks', class: 11, thisSec: false }, { id: 3, name: 'ali', class: 12, thisSec: true }, { id: 4, name: 'vicks', class: 11, thisSec: false }, { id: 5, name: 'nick', class: 10, thisSec: true }, { id: 6, name: 'lick', class: 12, thisSec: false }, ],

checkFilter = (id, searchCritera) => {
    if(id && searchCritera.length) {
        const selectedItem = data.find(item => item.id === id);
        const dataneeded = data.filter(
            o => o.id !== id && 
            searchCritera.every(key => o[key] === selectedItem[key])
        );       
        console.log('dataneeded ', dataneeded);
    }
};

checkFilter(1, [
    'name',
    'class'
]);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but I want to do it dynamically not just the name and class.

Comment: We sure can do that .... using `Array#every`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this filter

```
const checkFilter = (id, searchCritera) => {
    if(id && searchCritera.length) {
        var keyToIgnore = ["id"];
        const selectedItem = data.find(item => item.id === id)
        const targetWithoutSelectedItem = data.filter(item => item !== selectedItem);
        const targets = targetWithoutSelectedItem.filter(item => {
          return Object.keys(item).every(obj => keyToIgnore.includes(obj) || item[obj] === selectedItem[obj] );
        })

        console.log('dataneeded ', targets);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. let me try that.

Comment: can you please explain it a bit? thanks for the answer by the way

Comment: First you grab yourself the whole object with your provided id. Thats your "selectedItem". Then you make a copy of your array of objects but withyout your selected item. Thats why the "!==" is used (get all items that are not eaqual). Then you filter those items for following condition: get all keys of the object "item" and check if all values of "item" are the same as "selectedItem". But we want to ignore the id bc it will never be the same. Thats why there is the "includes" method. This returns always true for the id. So the condition is dependend on all other values than the id.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. but sorry it is not working as expected.
one thing is not clear here

data.filter(item => item !== selectedItem);

how are we comparing objects here? I think it'll always return false I guess

Comment: @AliMir yeah you are right. But you can use JSON.stringify. So like `const targetWithoutSelectedItem = data.filter(item => JSON.stringify(item) !== JSON.stringify(selectedItem));`